# Problem in using ansible plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I installed Ansible plugin in Jenkins and I configured.
I created ansible.cfg, hosts and the playbook files.
I pushed those files with directory in Bitbucket.
The issue is when I start a build in Jenkins it says "skipping: no hosts matched" or I have already tested the directory manually and it works.

This is jenkins configuration:
[image]

This the error message:

[image]

When i execute the ansible-playbook command directly from the folder in Desktop it works.

[image]

This is when i executed the command in the jenkins directory

[image]

Comment: What if you add this configuration to ansible.cfg file?
host_key_checking = False

Comment: The error you describe in the question does not match the error in the image you posted.

Comment: the ansible.cfg file the one that exists under /etc/ansible or the file that exists locally in the folder.
The problem is that in the jenkins folder it can't detect the host file even that it exists, it is like it is searching for it in the folder /etc/ansible/.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a credentials owner. When you run it manually you are identified (with an attached ssh key) but Jenkins needs some permissions.

Comment: The ssh key is configured because ansible needs it to execute and to connect with another server, also the ssh key is configured in Jenkins. The problem is with the inventory configuration.